# How to execute a method with a button click

Tags: c#, button, methods

How can I add a function to a button that will run a method I've created. I want to write out an array into a message dialog box with a press of a button, but I don't seem to be getting anywhere so i turned to stackoverflow for some help, since googling didn't really help me with my problem.

```
 static void Tractors(Tractor[] tractors)
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < tractors.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((i + 1) + ", " + tractors[i].ToString());
        }
    }
```

This is my function that writes out the table of "Tractors".

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

What should I write into the button1_click method so that it would work?

Comment: what kind of application is it? you need to add a click event on button

Comment: 1. Make a Click Event handler. 2. Register it with the button 3. Write function call into event, same way you write it into main or every other function. | The Designer can do 1+2 for you and I think it already did. | You function however is still trying to write the console, rather then a GUI Label. You need to fix that.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: In which class is defined the Tractors function? And if this is a GUI application writing out with Console.WriteLine will not show anything on your display but only in the debug window of Visual Studio

Comment: @Christopher ok so I can call all the functions like in other functions, but how do I call a function that requires parameters. For example, in my function that would be called in the event handler I would require an array of Tractors, but that array is created in the main method.

Comment: You need to declare/stroe the data you need at class level. Then you can pass them into your functions

Comment: How do I create a class that holds the array of objects and then fill it with values in the class itself?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the event handler with the button control and write the logic inside this event handler. If its windows form application you can do like this.

```
this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Call your methods here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would call `Tractor()` the exactly same way you call `Console.WriteLine()`. Both are static functions.

However the function is utterly messed up and propably not salvageable. The proper name would be `printTractorsToConsole()`. As it contains the `Console.WriteLine()` call, it is strongly tied to Console Applications - avoid tying functions to one Display Technology like that.

You need a more general function that creates and returns a string. You can then send that string to `WriteLine()`, assign it to `Label.Text` or *wherever else you want the string to be*.  Strings primarily exist for intput from or output towards the user - and there is too many ways to get it to them.

```
//Not tested against a compiler, may contain syntax errors
static string TractorArrayToString(Tractor[] tractors){
    string output = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < tractors.Length; i++)
    {
        output += (i + 1) + ", " + tractors[i].ToString()) + Environment.NewLine;
    }

    return output;
}
```

But even function might be a bad idea, as that function would tie all representations to a single format. Generally you would write that loop directly into the Click Event. But this function looks like it is for printing for debug purposes, so it might work.

Comment: Ok but how do I get the Array of Tractors into the click event? I can write the click event like this, but i don't know how to get the array in.                                                                                                                   
            private string button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string output = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < tractors.Length; i++)
                {
                    output += (i + 1) + ", " + tractors[i].ToString() +Environment.NewLine;
            }
       return output;
     }

Comment: @LukaBarlič You got the array of tractors as part of the Form/Window. Then teh event can access it.